# AdMob with Android Phonegap. Open native browser/market

Tags: android, cordova, admob

Is it possible to open AdMob web links in native browser and market links in market app?
I.e. now when I click on the add my Phonegap WebView overrides by Ad content and there is no way back except pressing Back button (I should click many times to go back in some cases).

I'm using Phonegap 1.0 and "Smartphone Web" AdMob.

Answer (score 0):

I would imagine this is a setting in the admob code you put in your UIWebView